# What is a prohibited database script?

Tags: acumatica

I ran into an error when publishing a customization project that I haven’t seen before:  “The '' customization project contains a prohibited database script”.  The customization has published without errors and the db script in it executes fine on many different Acumatica instances except for this particular one.  The db script just drops a view if it exists, and then creates the view.  The Acumatica build is 21.115.0017.  The error shows up right away after selecting Publish.  Did I miss something in the release notes somewhere where certain db commands are no longer allowed in scripts, or could it be a licensing or permissions issue of some kind?

Comment: As long as I have been aware, Acumatica has steered us away from SQL Views and pushed us to do projections.  However, I know we used on in a Hackathon a couple of years ago.  I don't think it would be licensing.  Is it a matter of local test instances working and cloud instance not?  That would make sense since they discourage views.  And can you pull off what you need with a PXProjection?

Comment: It's working in multiple SaaS and on-prem instances, but just not this particular instance for some reason.  I'm not sure if what I'm doing is possible with a projection, but I may try it if I can't figure out why only this one instance out of about 40 of them so far is failing.  Thanks Brian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is happening due to a 3rd party license manager from EIS that is installed on this one instance.

Comment: I added a related question on the Community forum....  https://community.acumatica.com/property-management-175/acumatica-and-imperium-and-license-manager-8547?postid=29271#post29271